# Not able to call generic method

Tags: java, generics

Here is my generic method signature:

```
public <T,R> R convertRFromT(T model, Class<R> response) {
  R responseInstance = response.newInstance();
  // perform some operations
  return responseInstance;
}
```

Now when I try to call this method with

```
convertRFromT(exampleClassInstance, ABC.class);
```

Here exampleClassInstance is instance of some class and ABC is another class which can be created from example. But I'm getting error here that exampleClassInstance, ABC.class can't be applied to T, `Class<R>`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the argument order is correct in your real code?

Comment: On what line do you get that error?

Comment: There's no point in `T` here: just use `Object model` instead.

Comment: I can find no error in the code you show here, I got it running. Can you show more of the code where you call the convertRFromT()?

Comment: I was using it in lambda function. Not sure if it was because of that then. is it possible?